# Store function pointer passed from a function

Tags: c

I'm trying to store a function pointer in a struct and can't make it works. Here's the code.

```
typedef enum { POUSSOIR, INTERRUPTEUR } Button_Type;
typedef struct Button {
    char name[20];
    Button_Type type;
    void(*action)(struct Button*);
    char input[20];
    char output[20];
} Button;

static Button buttons[7];

Button Button_Create(char *name, Button_Type type, void (*action), char input[20], char output[20]) {
    Button this;
    strcpy(this.name, name);
    this.type = type;
    this.action = (*action)(&this);
    strcpy(this.input, input);
    strcpy(this.output, output);
    return this;
}

void dimmer(Button *button) {
    LOG("dim!!!");
}

int init_Buttons() {
    buttons[0] = Button_Create("Salon", POUSSOIR, &dimmer, "DI04", "DMX_2");
    return 1;
}
```

What I want is to have many buttons with differents callbacks for on-off case or dimmable case and more. So I wan't to init each button with a callback function. Also I can't pass the Button reference to Button_Create function as it doesn't exit yet.
How can I acheive this ?

EDIT : SOLUTION

```
Button Button_Create(char *name, Button_Type type, void (*action)(Button*), char input[20], char output[20]) {
    Button this;
    strcpy(this.name, name);
    this.type = type;
    this.action = action;
    strcpy(this.input, input);
    strcpy(this.output, output);
    return this;
}

//as example
void *fn_ButtonThread(void *p_Data) {
    printf("Starting Button Thread.\r\n"); fflush(stdout);
    while(!exitFlag) {
      if (....) {
        // Call the function with parameters here
        buttons[0].action(&buttons[0]);
      }
    }
    printf("Stopping Button Thread.\r\n"); fflush(stdout);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't  ```this.action = (*action)(&this);``` be actually  ```this.action = action;``` ? You are calling a function that returns void and trying to assign that "void" to this.action, which won't be allowed.

Comment: So, it's because I'm trying to execute the function when I want to add &this in Button_Create, but it's in the (future) buttons loop I'll have to run action(&this).

Comment: Thanks, now it works !

Comment: `action` is a data pointer, `this->action` is a function pointer. You can not mix them. Storing a function pointer in a `void` pointer causes UB. But you can store any function pointer value in any other type of function pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The declaration of the `action` parameter in `Button_Create` and the setting of `this.action` is wrong. Here is a corrected version:

```
Button Button_Create(char *name, Button_Type type, void (*action)(Button *), char input[20], char output[20]) {
    Button this;
    strcpy(this.name, name);
    this.type = type;
    this.action = action;
    strcpy(this.input, input);
    strcpy(this.output, output);
    return this;
}
```

In the call to `Button_Create` you can change `&dimmer` to `dimmer`. It will work either way because `dimmer` is already considered to be a pointer to the function defined as `dimmer` and the `&` is ignored in this case. (Function pointers behave differently to object pointers in that regard.)

You could call a function defined as follows to invoke the action:

```
void Button_Press(Button *button) {
    button->action(button);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the precision of function pointer &. Also void (*action)(Button *) and void (*action) do the same, but I think it's cleaner your way as it's defined in the Button struct.

Comment: @JB_DELR `void (*action)` is the same as `void *action` (the parentheses are redundant there). A `void *` value can be used to point to an object, but technically it should not be used to point to a function.

Comment: But if I add (Button*) to void (*action)(Button *) it's pointing on a function pointer isn't it?

Comment: @JB_DELR `void (*action)(Button *)` declares `action` to be a pointer to a function that has a single parameter of type `Button *` and a return type of `void`. This matches your `dimmer` function, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Aren't the buttons created automatically by their declaration: static Button buttons[7];
They are not pointers, so that struct of 7 elements would be created. Also there are no system calls to CreateWindow etc.

Thus you can send &button[0] etc. as parameters to set their values. The code below compiles and prints "DI04" and  "DMX_2", VS2019. (I haven't tested the function pointers).

```
typedef enum { POUSSOIR, INTERRUPTEUR } Button_Type;
typedef struct Button {
    char name[20];
    Button_Type type;
    void(*action)(Button*);
    char input[20];
    char output[20];
} Button;

static Button buttons[7];

void LOG(const char* s) {
    printf_s(s);
}
void Button_Create(Button &b, const char* name, Button_Type type, void(*action)(Button*), const char input[20], const char output[20]) {
    //Button this;
    strcpy_s(b.name, name);
    b.type = type;
    b.action = action; // (*action)(&b);
    strcpy_s(b.input, input);
    strcpy_s(b.output, output);        
}

void dimmer(Button* button) {
    LOG("dim!!!");
}

int init_Buttons() {
    //buttons[0] = Button_Create("Salon", POUSSOIR, &dimmer, "DI04", "DMX_2");
    Button_Create(buttons[0], "Salon", POUSSOIR, &dimmer, "DI04", "DMX_2");
    printf_s(buttons[0].input);
    printf_s("\n");
    printf_s(buttons[0].output);
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    init_Buttons();

    return 0; //or whatever
}
enter code here
```

EDIT: (Button this; Ah plain C?... It's confusing with C++ this.
Without references &:

```
void Button_Create_Ptr(Button *b, const char* name, Button_Type type, void(*action)(Button*), const char input[20], const char output[20]) {
    //Button this;
    strcpy_s(b->name, name);
    b->type = type;
    b->action = action; // (*action)(&b);
    strcpy_s(b->input, input);
    strcpy_s(b->output, output);        
}
```

Then:
Button_Create_Ptr(&buttons[1], "Baloon", POUSSOIR, &dimmer, "GYZ1", "BTS2");

Comment: Yes, I'm trying POO programming in plain C, based on https://chgi.developpez.com/c/objet/